# Sign convention for spherical mirrors

Tags: optics, conventions, geometric-optics

What is the sign convention for this formulation of the spherical mirror equation?

$$1/i + 1/o = 1/f$$

f is negative for convex mirrors.
i is image distance.
o is object distance.

(How can the proper signs the numbers plugged in for i and o be determined?)

Answer (score 0):

Negative sign is used for virtual images.

For mirror, if the reflected ray comes where the radius of the curvature is and forms a real image, give a plus sign before i.

Otherwise, give minus sign.